# Nodejs use JOIN for two tables on sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to implementing this mysql command on sequelize, but as far as i'm newbie to use this library i can't implementing that

i want to make this sql command:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
join users_contacts_lists on users_contacts_lists.mobile_number = users.mobile_number 
WHERE users_contacts_lists.user_id = 1
```

My models to create database schema:

```
'use strict';
var config = require('../config');

var User = config.sequelize.define('users', {
    id: {
        type: config.Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    password: {
        type: config.Sequelize.STRING
    },
    username: {
        type: config.Sequelize.STRING
    },
    mobileNumber: {
        type: config.Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'mobile_number'
    },
    status: {
        type: config.Sequelize.STRING
    },
}, {freezeTableName: true});

var UsersContactsLists = config.sequelize.define('users_contacts_lists', {
    id: {
        type: config.Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    userId: {
        type: config.Sequelize.INTEGER,
        field: 'user_id'
    },
    mobileNumber: {
        type: config.Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'mobile_number', defaultValue: 0
    }
}, {freezeTableName: true});

UsersContactsLists.belongsTo(ChannelsTypes, {foreignKey: 'user_id'});
User.hasMany(Channels, {foreignKey: 'id'});

User.sync();
UsersContactsLists.sync();

module.exports =
{
    users: User,
    usersContactsLists: UsersContactsLists
};
```

how can i resolve this problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define the target key and the foreign key both in a relation like this:

```
User.belongsTo(UsersContactsLists, {targetKey:'mobileNumber',foreignKey: 'mobileNumber'});
```

And then you can use this:

```
User.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: UsersContactsLists,
        where: {
            userId: 1
        }
    }]
})
```

Comment: Thanks man, unfortunately i get this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'field' of undefined
    at new BelongsTo (/Volumes/Home/Projects/Web/test/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/belongs-to.js:64:66)`

Comment: Thanks, how can i choose some fields from `Users` and `UsersContactsLists` models? for example `id` from `User` and `updated_at` from `UsersContactsLists`?

Comment: the targetkey refers to target model that here is UsersContactsLists so targetKey will be `updated_at` and another is foriegnKey of current model that here is `id`

Comment: its wasn't my mean, create join `sql` command and select some fields from two tables

Comment: use something like this :                                                                                     `User.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: UsersContactsLists,
        where: {
            userId: 1
        },
        attributes: {'updated_at'}
    }],
    attributes: {'id'}
})`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128700/discussion-between-tux-world-and-farhadamjady).

Comment: User.findAll( 
{ include: [ 
{ model: UsersContactsLists, 
where: { userId: 1 }, 
attributes: ['updated_at'] 
}] 
, 
attributes: ['id'] 
} 
)

Answer (score 4):

Fiddled around a bit, does this statement do what you want?

```
User.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: UsersContactsLists,
        where: {
            userId: 1
        }
    }]
```